# Android Socket client doesn't connect to the server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to connect an android client to a pc server, but the client always crashes and doesn't connect to the server.
the server is composed of two methods, one that wait for a client to connect and another that print the client connected (I didn't use thread, i only connect one client) 
Server (i will show only the first method):

```
public Socket listeningClient () 
{
    try 
    {
        server = new ServerSocket(8080);
        client = server.accept();
        server.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return client;
}
```

in the client there are a button that call the method to create the socket on click:

Client

```
public class Client {
  String IP = "192.168.1.4";
  int portaServer = 8080;
  Socket miosocket = null;

  public void connetti() {
    try {
        InetAddress nomeServer = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        miosocket = new Socket(nomeServer, portaServer);
        miosocket.close();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MyApp", "UnknownHost");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MyApp", "Exception");
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

The app always crash at the line: `miosocket = new Socket(nomeServer, portaServer);`
and Throws the Exception(the second one). Can someone please tell me if is my code that is wrong(I'm pretty sure that the problem is the code) or there are problem on the server?

(in the AndroidManifest.xml I used these permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

)

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: i think is:     05-03 22:29:56.594 24077-24077/com.example.administrator.progetto W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ;
after this it gives me anothe system.err but it write something like 20 lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the exception you quoted in your comments, you cannot perform blocking IO on the main thread. You need to spawn a thread (or use `AsyncTask` and do the work there.

If you are really trying to host a server on an Android service, you should do so by creating a `Service` and using that to host a thread that starts the server and processes requests.